# How do you query the values of custom binary fields?

Tags: netsuite, suiteql

Given that I know CustomField information such as scriptid, id, internalid, and the associated table, how do I include that in a query against the associated table?

CustomField gives me the metadata, but I need to check the actual custom data / values.

It appears as though *some* custom fields are returned when querying the associated table, but not all. The "is" fields like isstored do not appear to be the differentiators, nor does fieldtype. In my case the fieldvaluetype is Document; is that the issue?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it's not possible for binary fields. I heard from Tim Dietrich, an expert who [blogs](https://timdietrich.me/) on NetSuite and SuiteQL:

> Unfortunately, SuiteQL doesn't support binary fields, or long text fields.